# how to refresh listview after deleting item in the adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, google-cloud-firestore, popupmenu

in my adapter I added OnLongClickListener() and it opens a popup menu that when you press deletes that item from the listview and the firestore but I didn't succeed in refreshing my listview so when I delete the item will disappear.

I used notifyDataSetChanged() and it works when I add a new item but when I delete an item it doesn't work

My ListView:
public class NotesLV extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

private ListView listView;
private FirebaseFirestore db;
private static final String TAG="ALMA";
private ArrayList<Notes> allNotes;

private ArrayList<Notes> noNotes= new ArrayList<>();
private String mail;
private FloatingActionButton floatingbtn;

private NotesLVAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_notes_lv);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    floatingbtn = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floatingActionButton);
    floatingbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(NotesLV.this, CreateNote.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
        }
    });


    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mail = user.getEmail().toString();

    //notes.add("Example Note");
    //arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, notes);
    allNotes = new ArrayList<>();
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    Log.d(TAG, "listview");
    adapter = new NotesLVAdapter(NotesLV.this, allNotes);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    //loadNotesToListView();
}


public void loadNotesToListView(){
    allNotes.clear();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.d(TAG,"loading");
    db.collection("Folder").document(mail).collection("Notes").orderBy("date",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
            // after getting the data we are calling on success method
            // and inside this method we are checking if the received
            // query snapshot is empty or not.
            if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty())
            {
                // if the snapshot is not empty we are hiding
                // our progress bar and adding our data in a list.
                List<DocumentSnapshot> list = queryDocumentSnapshots.getDocuments();
                Log.d(TAG, "List size: " + list.size());
                for (DocumentSnapshot d : list) {
                    // after getting this list we are passing
                    // that list to our object class.
                    Notes notes = d.toObject(Notes.class);
                    //Log.d("TOSTRING", ""+notes.getDate());
                    d.getId();
                    // after getting data from Firebase we are
                    // storing that data in our array list
                    allNotes.add(notes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "added");
                }
                // after that we are passing our array list to our adapter class.
                adapter = new NotesLVAdapter(NotesLV.this, allNotes);

                // after passing this array list to our adapter
                // class we are setting our adapter to our list view.
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                Log.d(TAG, "adapter was set");

            }
            else
            {
                Log.d(TAG,"No data found in query");
                // if the snapshot is empty we are displaying a toast message.
                Toast.makeText(NotesLV.this, "No data found in Database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
            // we are displaying a toast message
            // when we get any error from Firebase.
            Toast.makeText(NotesLV.this, "Fail to load data..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    loadNotesToListView();
}
```

}

my adapter:
public class NotesLVAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private FirebaseFirestore db;
private String mail;

public NotesLVAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Notes> notes) {
    super(context, 0, notes);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;

    if (listItemView==null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_notes_d,parent, false);
    }

    Notes notes = getItem(position);
    db= FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mail= user.getEmail().toString();
    TextView tvNTitle = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNoteName);
    tvNTitle.setText(notes.getNoteName());
    TextView tvNDate = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
    tvNDate.setText(notes.getSavedDate());
    ImageView imageBoss=(ImageView)listItemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBoss);
    String pic="";
    listItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("ALMA","clicked");
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CreateNote.class);
            intent.putExtra("title",tvNTitle.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("content",notes.getContent().toString());
            intent.putExtra("reminder",notes.needReminder());
            intent.putExtra("saved date",notes.getSavedDate().toString());
            intent.putExtra("date",notes.getDate().toString());
            view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    listItemView.setOnLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popupMenu=new PopupMenu(view.getContext(), view);
            popupMenu.setGravity(Gravity.END);
            popupMenu.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.notes_popup_menu,popupMenu.getMenu());
            popupMenu.show();
            popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    int id=menuItem.getItemId();

                    if(id==R.id.menu_edit) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CreateNote.class);
                        intent.putExtra("title",tvNTitle.getText().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("content",notes.getContent().toString());
                        intent.putExtra("reminder",notes.needReminder());
                        intent.putExtra("date",notes.getDate().toString());
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    if(id==R.id.menu_delete){
                        // below line is for getting the collection
                        // where we are storing our courses.
                        db.collection("Folder").document(mail).collection("Notes").document(notes.getNoteName()+", "+notes.getSavedDate()).delete()
                                // after deleting call on complete listener
                                // method to delete this data.
                                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        // inside on complete method we are checking
                                        // if the task is success or not.
                                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                            // this method is called when the task is success
                                            // after deleting we are starting our MainActivity.
                                            Log.d("ALMA","deleted");
                                        } else {
                                            // if the delete operation is failed
                                            // we are displaying a toast message.
                                            Log.d("ALMA","didnt delete");
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            return true;
        }
    });

    return listItemView;
}
```

}

Comment: You need to add `onDataChanged` so that your list is reloaded everytime the data changes in the database.

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: If you understand Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or even this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.